# In .NET Core 6 class library Render Razor Pages into string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

I'm working on a .NET Core class library project, and I want to send emails through the SendGrid API with HTML content. I'm planning to create various email templates using `.cshtml` pages and layouts.

Could you guide me on how to render these `.cshtml` pages to strings so that I can use them as content for my emails? I've explored different solutions, but many seem to be outdated or no longer supported.

Comment: You don't need any kind of specialty _Razor-to-string-to-email component_: you can do the two parts separately: rendering a Razor view to a string _first_, is well-known ground - and passing the string off to a SendGrid API request is also straightforward.

Comment: @Dai can you please provide a piece of code that can be used in .NET Core 6 class library application ?

Comment: See the linked duplicate.